# Как проверять условие вхождения в цикл внутри тела цикла

Tags: python, циклы, while, условия

```
import time
now = time.time()
trial = 1663764660
while True:
    if now < trial:
        print('Работаем')
    else:
        print('Стоп')
        exit(0)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Есть простая програмка, которая в цикле while проверяет условие для вхождения в цикл, как можно её переделать что бы условие проверялось прямо во время работы цикла? Чтоб было более понятно приведу пример: сейчас если условие выполняется при старте то каждые 2 секунды выводит в консоль 'Работаем', если нет то 1 раз выводит 'Стоп', то есть или-или а хотелось бы, чтоб условие как-то проверялось во время работы цикла когда он уже печатает 'Работаем' и если оно изменилось то цикл завершался выводом 'Стоп'

Comment: Не нужно заменять код скриншотом. Код должен быть в вопросе текстом, а не картинками.

Comment: sleep синхронная операция, пока она выполняется, вы ничего проверить не можете

Comment: ну так ты изменяй now в цикле. А то один раз посмотрел и потом с одним и тем же значением работаешь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, что совсем понял задачу, но вроде бы так ...

```
from time import time, sleep

trial = time() + 6  # + 6 секунд к текущему времени, чтобы отработать трижды по 2 секунды :)
while time() < trial:
    print('Работаем')
    sleep(2)
print('Стоп')
```

```
Работаем
Работаем
Работаем
Стоп
```

Answer (score 0):

Это помогло, спасибо.

```
import time

now = time.time()
trial = 1663773931         # unixcode

while time.time() < trial:
    print('Работаем')
    time.sleep(2)

print('Стоп')
```